# Select average amount by half of the year in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a such a table in my db

| id | amount | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 2020-02-02 22:14:56 |
| 2 | 20 | 2020-05-29 22:14:56 |
| 3 | 20 | 2020-08-29 22:14:56 |
| 4 | 40 | 2020-12-29 22:14:56 |

My result should like this

| amount | half_of_year |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 1 (1st half) |
| 30 | 2 (2nd half) |

I need calculate average **amount** according to first and second half of the year and show them separately

I have no idea how to select and group by date

Comment: How your average is 30 in 2nd half ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
select AVG(amount) amount,'1 (1st half)' as half_of_year
from <your_Table>
where year(created_at)=2020 and month(created_at)<=6
UNION ALL
select AVG(amount), '2 (2nd half)' as half_of_year
from <your_Table>
where year(created_at)=2020 and month(created_at)>6
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT YEAR(date) `year`,
       (MONTH(date) > 6) + 1 `half`, 
       AVG(amount) avg_amount
FROM  source_table
GROUP BY 1, 2
```